# Undefined References even though .bib file is present in same directory

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, texstudio, biber

Whenever i am compiling my main.tex with ref.bib file in Texstudio it is not showing the references and telling `Empty bibliography`. The log is showing this

```
33: Citation 'Valiant1979CompletenessCI' on page 2 undefined
33: Citation 'Mahajan1997ACA' on page 2 undefined
33: Citation 'completeburg' on page 2 undefined
33: Citation 'ramsurvey' on page 2 undefined
33: Citation 'shpilkasurvey' on page 2 undefined
: There were undefined references.
: Please (re)run Biber on the file:(biblatex) document(biblatex) and rerun LaTeX afterwards.
```

My main.tex contains

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\graphicspath{{Images/}{./}}
\usepackage{booktabs,hyperref}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amsmath}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=alphabetic]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{ref.bib}
\useinnertheme{circles}
\title[SOmething]{SOmething SOmething} 
\author[Soham Chatterjee]{Soham Chatterjee}
\institute[ABC]{ABCInstitute \\ \smallskip \textit{xyz@gmail.com}}
\date[\today]{\today}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \titlepage
\end{frame}

\subsection{Results on Classes}


\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Some results on these classes}
    \begin{itemize}
 \item $VF\subseteq VBP \subseteq VP \subseteq VNP$
 \item Any circuit of size $s$ and depth $d$ can be converted to a formula of size $s^d$ 
        \item $VP$ is contained in $VNP$ and it is believed that this containment is strict (Valiant's Hypothesis \cite{Valiant1979CompletenessCI}).
     \item $VP= VNP\implies \#P=FP\implies P= NP$
     \item $DET$ is $VBP-complete$ \cite{Mahajan1997ACA}
     \item $PERM$ is $VNP-complete$ \cite{completeburg}
     \item There are other structural results that are well written in \cite{ramsurvey} and \cite{shpilkasurvey}
     \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

My ref.bib file contains

```
@article{Valiant1979CompletenessCI,
  title={Completeness classes in algebra},
  author={Leslie G. Valiant},
  journal={Proceedings of the eleventh annual ACM symposium on Theory of computing},
  year={1979}
}
@inproceedings{Mahajan1997ACA,
    title={A combinatorial algorithm for the determinant},
    author={Meena Mahajan and V. Vinay},
    booktitle={ACM-SIAM Symposium on Discrete Algorithms},
    year={1997}
}
@article{completeburg,
    author = {Bürgisser, Peter},
    year = {1998},
    month = {08},
    pages = {},
    title = {Completeness and Reduction in Algebraic Complexity Theory},
    volume = {7},
    doi = {10.1007/978-3-662-04179-6_1}
}
@article{ramsurvey,
    title={A survey of lower bounds in arithmetic circuit complexity},
    author={Ramprasad Saptharishi},
    url = {https://github.com/dasarpmar/lowerbounds-survey},
    year = 2021
}
@article{shpilkasurvey,
    author = {Shpilka, Amir and Yehudayoff, Amir},
    year = {2010},
    month = {01},
    pages = {207-388},
    title = {Arithmetic Circuits: A survey of recent results and open questions},
    volume = {5},
    journal = {Foundations and Trends in Theoretical Computer Science},
    doi = {10.1561/0400000039}
}
```

Comment: and did you run biber? What does the blg-file say?

Comment: when i run biber it is showing INFO - This is Biber 2.19
INFO - Logfile is 'ref.bib.blg'
ERROR - Cannot find 'ref.bib.bcf'!
INFO - ERRORS: 1  and .bbl is empty

Comment: You need to run biber with `biber filename_of_your_document` (no file ending), not the name of your bib file. If your tex file is called `example.tex`, you need to run `biber example`

Comment: ... and then you should also add something like `\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}` to your document

Comment: When I am running individually pdflatex then biber then pdflatex the document is generating correctly but in texstudio it is not happening

Comment: @SohamChatterjee See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154751/biblatex-with-biber-configuring-my-editor-to-avoid-undefined-citations

Comment: @SohamChatterjee Can you show a screenshot of the `Commands` tab in your texstudio preferences?

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz That answer helped actually. My default bibliography tool was biblatex not biber that's why it was not compiling the .bib file

Comment: @SohamChatterjee Great to hear that you could solve your problem!